# Sqlalchemy type object 'table' has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert data inside a table which is throwing me an error saying
`type object 'table' has no attribute 'insert'.` I don't know how to fix this issue as i am quite new to python.

data which is am trying to insert is:

```
data_to_insert = [('123123', '456456', 'LULU', 'Scheduled', 'Risk Level 5/Planned Service Interruption', '5G Addition', '2G/3G/4G/5G RADIO ACCESS NETWORK Reduced Lead Time Activities', 'NCOR_MBR_041 RBS Shut down required as directed by building owner or other site constraints', 'Normal', 'New 5G Base'), ('123124', '456457', 'LULI', 'Scheduled', 'Risk Level 5/Planned Service Interruption', '5G Addition', '2G/3G/4G/5G RADIO ACCESS NETWORK Reduced Lead Time Activities', 'NCOR_MBR_041 RBS Shut down required as directed by building owner or other site constraints', 'Normal', 'New 5G Base')]
```

Below is the code which i am trying to run:

```
for row in data_to_insert:
    if not session.query(table_to_add).filter_by(cmart_id=row.cmart_id, drake_id=row.drake_id, impacted_nodecode=row.impacted_nodecode, cmart_status=row.cmart_status).first():
       session.execute(table_to_add.insert().values(**row))
       print("row insert : ", row.cmart_id, row.cmart_status)
    else:
       print("row exist : ", row.cmart_id, row.cmart_status)
       log.info('--insert_table_func data already exists')
```

and below is the  insert query which i am using:

```
session.execute(table_to_add.insert().values(**row))
```

Error : `type object 'table' has no attribute 'insert'`

I am stuck with this issue and quite confused on how to solve it.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].